# react leaflet -layer control -satellite view

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, leaflet, react-leaflet

I want to use the leaflet map on my react project and I would like to add a layer control where the user can switch between street view and satellite view.
I am trying to use google satellite view, but it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code

```
function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MapContainer center={[40.44695, -345.23437]} zoom={2}>
        <LayersControl>
          <BaseLayer checked name="OpenStreetMap">
            <TileLayer
              url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
              attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            />
          </BaseLayer>

          <BaseLayer name="Satellite View">
            <TileLayer
                url='https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'
                maxZoom= {20}
              />
            
          </BaseLayer>
        </LayersControl>
      </MapContainer>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[Satellite View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8CU4.png)

Thank you very much

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: I can't see anything on the satellite view. I do not have  any errors. I don't why. is it the browsers fault? I am using Firefox. I am going to add a screenshot to show what i am seeing.

Comment: In the network tab of developer tools do you see requests going out to the google tile server and returning successfully or are there no requests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tile url you are using for Google maps does not exist:

`https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}`

From the Leaflet docs:

> {s} means one of the available subdomains (used sequentially to help
> with browser parallel requests per domain limitation; subdomain values
> are specified in options; a, b or c by default, can be omitted), {z} —
> zoom level, {x} and {y} — tile coordinates. {r} can be used to add
> "@2x" to the URL to load retina tiles.

The urls you are requesting are using the default subdomains `a`, `b` and `c` which all appear broken:

- https://a.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x=1&y=1&z=1
- https://b.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x=1&y=1&z=1
- https://c.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x=1&y=1&z=1

It looks like the correct subdomains are `mt1`, `mt2` and `mt3`. You can specify them using the `subdomains` prop:

```
<TileLayer
   url='https://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}'
   maxZoom= {20}
   subdomains={['mt1','mt2','mt3']}
/>
```

https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x=1&y=1&z=1